# print XPS from memory stream

Tags: c#, printing, aspose, printdialog, xpsdocument

I use c# 
I need to print DOCX, I send the docx to server , convert it to XPS and return XPS as memory stream.  convert docx by aspose.
 At client I use next code:

```
System.IO.Stream docStream = ...any xps as stream;
Package package = Package.Open(docStream);

//Create URI for Xps Package
//Any Uri will actually be fine here. It acts as a place holder for the
//Uri of the package inside of the PackageStore
string inMemoryPackageName = string.Format("memorystream://{0}.xps",         Guid.NewGuid());
Uri packageUri = new Uri(inMemoryPackageName);

//Add package to PackageStore
PackageStore.AddPackage(packageUri, package);

XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Maximum, inMemoryPackageName);
FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocumentSequence = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
        XpsDocument xpsDoc = new 
        dlg.PrintDocument(fixedDocumentSequence .DocumentPaginator, "Document title");


PackageStore.RemovePackage(packageUri);
xpsDoc.Close();
```

It work excellent with english, but I print documents with hebrew and arabic too. And in hebrew and arabic order of words is correct, but print every word vice versa.
If I write memory stream on disk as XPS and open it , the text is correct.

Comment: Have you tried to print the XPS after saving it to disk? Please try to print document on different machine. If you still face problem, please share your input Word document for testing. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: hello.
If I save file on the disk , and print it by XPSViewer , it's correct.
If I save the stream on the disk and open  and print it from c# , it's incorrect like print without save.

Comment: Please note that Aspose.Words requires TrueType fonts when printing document. You need to install fonts that are used in your document on the machine where you are printing the document. Please share your input document via Dropbox for investigation. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: I don't print by aspose. I use aspose for convert docx to xps only. What for  do I need TrueType fonts ?

Comment: Aspose.Words requires TrueType fonts when printing or rendering document to fixed file format e.g. PDF, XPS. Please share your document and procedure you are using for printing. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.